# Алгоритм, считающий сколько дней прошло от определенной даты

Tags: алгоритм, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть ли у кого алгоритм, считающий сколько дней прошло от определенной даты? И есть ли у кого соображения, как это написать? Есть ли функции такие? На ум пришло только дни поделить на 365,25, месяцы на 12, а разницу в годах умножить на 365,25... но получается не точно. Хочется, что-то вроде:

```
<?
/* YYYYmmdd - это высчитать и соединить легко, допустим 20110920 */
$today = $YYYYmmdd;

/* $amoon - от какого дня считаем */
$moon = 19690721;

/* дальше мы как то считаем это )) /*
echo "Америкосы были на луне ".$raznica." дней назад.";
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$today = time();
$moon = mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 21, 1969);
echo "Америкосы были на луне ".floor(($today - $moon) / 86400)." дней назад.";
```

Comment: Потрясающе! Гениально! Ахренеть! Автор аццкий сотона! Спасибо! Так все просто...

Answer (score 2):

Ну это очень грубо. Хотя у меня тоже грубовато достаточно и не стал решения делать для дат которые меньше 1970 года. (Просто было лень.)

```
function vypiska($skolko, $chego)
{
    global $array;
    if ($skolko == 0)
        $skolko = 10;
    if ($skolko == 1)
        $a = 3 * $chego + 1;
    if ($skolko >= 2 && $skolko <= 4)
        $a = 3 * $chego + 2;
    if ($skolko >= 5 && $skolko <= 20)
        $a = 3 * $chego + 3;
    if ($skolko > 20 && $skolko < 100)
        return vypiska($skolko % 10, $chego);
    if ($skolko >= 100)
        return vypiska($skolko % 100, $chego);
    return $array[$a];
}

$array = array(
    "",
    "день",
    "дня",
    "дней",
    "месяц",
    "месяца",
    "месяцев",
    "год",
    "года",
    "лет"
);

$std   = $_GET['d'];
$ed    = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m,d,Y"));
$e     = abs($ed - $std);
$f     = date('j-n-Y', $e);
$dat   = explode("-", $f);
$day   = $dat[0] - 1;
$month = $dat[1] - 1;
$year  = $dat[2] - 1970;
$soob  = $text . " ";

if ($year != 0)
    $soob = $soob . $year . " " . vypiska($year, 2);
if ($year != 0 && $month != 0 && $day != 0)
    $soob = $soob . ", ";
if ($year != 0 && $month != 0 && $day == 0)
    $soob = $soob . " и ";
if ($month == 0 && $day != 0 && $year != 0)
    $soob = $soob . " и ";
if ($month != 0)
    $soob = $soob . $month . " " . vypiska($month, 1);
if ($month != 0 && $day != 0)
    $soob = $soob . " и ";
if ($day != 0)
    $soob = $soob . $day . " " . vypiska($day, 0) . ".";
```

Comment: `mktime(0,0,0,date("m,d,Y"));` o_O

Comment: Пришлось считать именно так, чтобы получалось точнее сколько лет, месяцев и дней прошло или осталось до даты.

Comment: А вы скрипт проверяли, он работает?

Comment: если бы не работал то наверное я бы его не приводил тут. вот пример его работы - http://line.simsru.com